# how to Find the element with the class “values”, and tell us what the element contains in the following page https://theplan.co.uk/support-applicant/

Tags: javascript

I seem to struggle with answering this question withing the following link : https://theplan.co.uk/support-applicant/

Answer (score 0):

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for getting the tag, and [innterText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) for getting the right content of the tag (with the current html both return the same).

```js
console.log('innerText', document.querySelector('.values').innerText);

console.log('textContent', document.querySelector('.values').textContent);
```

```html
<p>We're looking for someone to join our growing Customer Support team! <span class="values">Obsessing over our users</span> is one of the key Hotjar values, so you'll help us continue to deliver outstanding support.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities that come to mind immediately:
`querySelector` and `getElementsByClassName`

Like @Totati, I would also prefer the querySelector.

```
document.querySelector('.values').innerText
// output: "Obsessing over our users"

elem = document.getElementsByClassName('values')[0].innerText
// output: "Obsessing over our users"
```